# Combine few same SELECT queries into one with set of "where"-data

Tags: sql, clickhouse

My query is simple, like:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM abc.def
WHERE a = 'some_a_value' AND b = 'some_b_value';
```

But I need get data for collection of "input values", like this:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM abc.def
WHERE
    (a = 'some_a_value' AND b = 'some_b_value')
    OR (a = 'another_a_value' AND b = 'another_b_value')
    OR ___etc.___
```

And also I need to now which result is for which source data. it's pretty easy to do it in PostgreSQL:

```sql
WITH src AS 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM 
        (VALUES (1, 'hello', 'world'),
                (2, 'test', 'data'),
                (3, 'more', 'data')) as bla_bla(num, text_a, text_b)
)
SELECT s.num, t.a, t.b, t.useful_data
FROM my_table AS t
JOIN src AS s ON (t.a = s.text_a AND t.b = s.text_b);
```

But Clickhouse **doesn't** allow using `VALUES` inside `WITH`.
At the moment I've found only one solution:

```sql
WITH src AS 
(
    SELECT 1 AS num, 'some_a_data' AS a, 'some_b_data' AS b
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2 AS num, 'another_a_data' AS a, 'another_b_data' AS b
    UNION ALL __&_etc.__
)
SELECT __&_etc.__
```

Is it correct or only way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found solution by myself. Clickhouse allows to use `VALUES` inside `WITH`, but unlike Postgres, `VALUES` should not be covered by braces

```sql
WITH src AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES (
        'num int, msg String',
        (1, 'hello'),
        (2, 'world'),
        (3, '!')
    )
)
SELECT * FROM src;

-- Results:
-- num|msg  |
-- ---+-----+
--   1|hello|
--   2|world|
--   3|!    |
```

But user needs extra privileges to do it:  `SQL Error [497] [07000]: Code: 497. DB::Exception: mike_pryadko: Not enough privileges. To execute this query it's necessary to have grant CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ON *.*. (ACCESS_DENIED)`

Another way - array of tuples:

```sql
WITH [
    ('hello', 'world', 'en'),
    ('hola', 'mundo', 'es'),
    ('привет', 'мир', 'ru')
] AS src
SELECT a, b, lang
FROM (SELECT null)
ARRAY JOIN
    arrayMap(src -> src.1, src) AS a,
    arrayMap(src -> src.2, src) AS b,
    arrayMap(src -> src.3, src) AS lang,
    arrayEnumerate(src) AS idx;

-- Result:
-- a     |b    |lang|
-- ------+-----+----+
-- hello |world|en  |
-- hola  |mundo|es  |
-- привет|мир  |ru  |
```

Answer (score 0):

i believe that you should try to create different steps and then UNION your data..

for example:

```
 WITH src_1 AS (
    SELECT * FROM ( VALUES 
        (1, 'hello', 'world'),
        (2, 'test', 'data'),
        (3, 'more', 'data')
    ) as bla_bla(num, text_a, text_b)
),
src_2 AS (
        (4, 'hello', 'world'),
        (5, 'test', 'data'),
        (6, 'more', 'data')
) as bla_bla(num, text_a, text_b)

SELECT bla_bla
FROM src_1
UNION ALL
SELECT bla_bla
    FROM src_2
```

This way you'll have control of what you are modificating in every step and if the ouptput it's not what's expected, go back and check in the CTE that's wrong/missing stg.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but you don't understand me: I need query for Clickhouse so I can't use `VALUES` inside of `WITH`. My Postgres example is just to show what result of query I want get.